# PL/SQL Oracle 10g Ask user for input (other than substitution variable)

Tags: oracle, input, plsql, oracle10g

pseudo code:

```
declare
    n number(10);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Welcome to Oracle');
    dbms_output.put_line('1. Insert');
    dbms_output.put_line('2. Delete');
    dbms_output.put_line('Choose an option');

    n:=&choice;

    if(n=1)
        .....
        .....
    else
        ....
        ....
    end if;
end;
```

I am getting a problem here.  When I try to run it, it asks for '&choice' first and after that it shows the dbms_output.put_line() statements.

But I want to show choices first and then ask for user for their input.

sample output (how I want it):

```
 Welcome to Oracle
 1. Insert
 2. Delete
 Choose an option:
 Enter the value for choice:
```

so what is the solution for this? is there any other way to take input from user?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do that in PL/SQL since it is not interactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PL/SQL is not interactive, so you cannot do that in PL/SQL.**

Using `&` to prompt user for an input is a `SQL*Plus` command and not in `PL/SQL`. PL/SQL is executed inside the database engine and cannot access the **terminal window** or the **GUI tool** like **SQL Developer** etc.

Having said that, you could pass parameters.

For example,

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    prompt_input NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    dbms_output.put_line('Welcome to Oracle');
  5    dbms_output.put_line('1. Insert');
  6    dbms_output.put_line('2. Delete');
  7    dbms_output.put_line('Choose an option');
  8    prompt_input := '&1';
  9    IF prompt_input = 1
 10    THEN
 11    dbms_output.put_line('You have selected '||prompt_input||' .Insert');
 12    ELSE
 13    dbms_output.put_line('You have selected '||prompt_input||' . Delete');
 14    END IF;
 15  END;
 16  /
Enter value for 1: 1
old   8:   prompt_input := '&1';
new   8:   prompt_input := '1';
Welcome to Oracle
1. Insert
2. Delete
Choose an option
You have selected 1 .Insert

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Agreed. If the OP has a solution that requires this kind of interactivity PL/SQL is definitely not the solution to the problem.

Comment: @mmmmmpie, Yes, OP needs to provide an interface to the user to input the data, just like any other application does.